# How do I represent a function in a plot in R (New to this)

Tags: r

How can I represent this function: y=-2*log(x) in a plot in R ? I am new to this programming language, any help will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [curve](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/curve) to draw a function plot over an interval.

Comment: There is the `quantile` function. Look into it

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
y <- function(x) {-2*log(x)}
plot(y, 0, 1, ylab="y", xlab="x", lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now for a box plot is the same ?

Comment: for functions, it is better to use the curve eg `curve(-2 * log(x))`

Comment: @Onyambu this is for a college work and I am supposed to calculate the quantile function of "-2 * log(x)" is there any quantile function in R I may use ?